# How to send dict of dict from Django to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, vue.js

I want to send data from Django to JavaScript so I can write all logic in JS + Vue and keep html clean.

In Django I have

```
context={'names':{'fn':'john','ln':'cena'}}
return render(request,'app/page1.html',context)
```

in `page1.html` template I have

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var names="{{names}}"; </script>
```

In javascript how can I access `names.fn` & `names.ln` ?

I have two more related questions:

1. Is this a preferred Django way to send data directly from Django to JS when template is rendered. (The only other method I know is through Ajax call. Here I dont want to do additional Ajax call after the page is rendered)
2. From security stand point, is it better to keep Django data related logic `{% if x > y %}` inside templates or is it ok to move the logic part to JS + Vue and just keep data structure in the template. I ask this because when i check page source in a browser window, I can see entire JS code but I cannot see anything that's inside a Django condition statement in html : `{% if x>y %} ----THIS IS INVISIBLE IN A BROWSER---- {% endif %}`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script):

```
{{names|json_script("names")}}
```

and then, in JS:

```
var names = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('names').textContent);
```

Alternately, install [`django-jsonify`](https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonify/); then, you can directly say

```
{% load jsonify %}
<script type="text/javascript"> var names={{names|jsonify}}; </script>
```

As for your second question: everything Vue (or Angular or React or Ractive or Knockout...) does is clientside, everything Django does is serverside. If you're building a Single-Page Application, you should prefer to do as much as possible using Vue (or Angular or React or Ractive or Knockout...); if you are not, then you likely don't need such a framework.

Comment: `pip install django-jsonify` instead of `pip install jsonify`.